# Module::Build and value substitution in files

Tags: perl, module-build

I'm starting to use Module::Build. During the build process I need to do value substitution in some files - changing paths based on installation location etc.

Cannot find anything in Module::Build documentation. I understand that I can extend Module::Build to do nearly anything, but is there some standard way how to do this?

Comment: I have example code for this in http://stackoverflow.com/a/5267728. This will be part of [my talk at YAPC](http://act.yapc.eu/ye2012/talk/4065).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a [Module::Build](https://www.metacpan.org/module/Module%3a%3aBuild%3a%3aCookbook) subclass and add an action to process your template. Override the appropriate targets to make that step a dependency. Start with [Module::Build::Cookbook](https://www.metacpan.org/module/Module%3a%3aBuild%3a%3aCookbook).